# How to read text between delimiter an fill it to variable

Tags: python

I have list of lines in this format:

```
Boston > Los Angeles > Houston
Boston > New York > Boston
Boston > San Francisco
Washington > Boston
Los Angeles > Houston
```

And I need work with individual cities - for example for first line I need have in variables Boston and LA and for second step LA and Houston. In input could be variable count of cities, but it will be allways in format city > city2 > city 3 ...

Comment: "For first line I need have in variables Boston and LA and for second step LA and Houston" Why? How does this logically follow from your input? What would be third, fourth, fifth step?

Comment: `bo, la, ho = 'Boston > Los Angeles > Houston'.split(' > ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> line = 'Boston > Los Angeles > Houston'
>>> cities = line.split(' > ')
>>> for x, y in zip(cities, cities[1:]):
        print(x, '---', y)

Boston --- Los Angeles
Los Angeles --- Houston
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input is, e.g., like this: `list_of_lines = ["Boston > Los Angeles > Houston, "Boston > New York > Boston"]` you will get the cities by simply splitting the line by the `>` delimiter:

```
for line in list_of_lines:
   city1, city2, city3 = line.split(">")
   # do stuff here
```